# How can I move all elements to another wrapping element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have two lists (`#product` and `#cart`).  People can click on an item and move it to the second list one at a time.  But I am looking to allow people to add ALL items in the first list to the second list.  And the reverse as well — remove all items from cart.

Can you help?

Here's my html:

```
<h2>Product List</h2>
<a id="add-all">Add all items to cart</a>
<ul id="product">
    <li id="item1">item 1</li>
    <li id="item3">item 3</li>
    <li id="item5">item 5</li>
</ul>

<h2>Shopping Cart</h2>
<a id="remove-all">Remove all items</a>
<ul id="cart">
    <li id="item2">item 2<input type="hidden" name="cartItems" value="item2"></li>
    <li id="item4">item 4<input type="hidden" name="cartItems" value="item4"></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see above, when an item is individually added to the cart, I `.append` an `input` tag with the same id.

The rough jQuery looks something like this:

```
$('#product').on('click','li', function() {
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    var itemLabel = $(this).html();
    var newItemLabel = itemLabel + '<input type="hidden" name="cartItems" value="' + itemID + '">';
    $(this).remove();
    $('#cart').append('<li id="' + itemID + '">' + newItemLabel + '</li>');
});
```

This works just fine one at a time.  But I'm stuck trying to iterate through each item in the product list to add all (or remove all).

Can you point me in the right direction?

Especially since I need to add an input element for every list item.  So I can't just take the `html()` of `#product` and append to `#cart` without looping through each one and appending an input.

**Tl;dr**

1. `#add-all` click should move all items in `#product` to `#cart`,
   appending an `input` to each
2. `#remove-all` click should move all items in `#cart` to `#product`,
   removing all `input` tags
3. how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis would work for add- all

```
$('#add-all').on('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').each(function (index, item) {
    $(item).append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cartItems\" value=\"" + $(item).attr('id') + "\"/>");
    $('#cart').append($(item));
  });
});
```

You could follow a similar logic for remove all.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcXpY/

Check this fiddle for the remove all code as well : http://jsfiddle.net/hcXpY/2/

```
$('#remove-all').on('click', function () {
  $(this).siblings('ul').find('li').each(function (index, item) {
    $(item).find('input').remove();
    $('#products').append($(item));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with iteration?

```
$('#product li').each( function() {
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    var itemLabel = $(this).html();
    var newItemLabel = itemLabel + '<input type="hidden" name="cartItems" value="' + itemID + '">';
    $(this).remove();
    $('#cart').append('<li id="' + itemID + '">' + newItemLabel + '</li>');
    removeDuplicatesFromCart();
});

function removeDuplicatesFromCart()
{
 //now remove any duplicates if there are in the carts
}
```

Comment: I'm not having a problem with duplicates.  Just add all, remove all.  There should never be an item in both lists anyway.

Comment: In that case, i guess you can simply use the code that I have shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do something simple like this:

```
$("#add-all").click(function() {
    $("#products").children().appendTo("#cart");
});
$("#remove-all").click(function() {
    $("#cart").children().appendTo("#products");
});
```

And, then you can add to this, the code to add/remove the `<input>` tag or just always have the input tag present and have it hidden via CSS when not in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class of remove to each product li that needs to be removed. Then loop though all the children of products, if the li has a class of remove, add it to the cart.

Adding the class

```
$('ul#products li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('remove');
});
```

Looping

```
$('ul#products li').each( function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('remove')){
       $(this).appendTo('#cart');
    }
});
```

You need something to trigger the aforementioned, button?